# How Can I use 2 Cpanel hosts separately

Tags: web, hosting, cpanel, web-hosting, host

I bought 2 Cpanel hosts with different speeds. One of them is supposed to be a host for downloading (and it's bigger) and the other host is going to host the main app.

Here's the problem:
How I can bind them with each other???